# Code the Hailstone sequence, Print the sequence for a range of any positive whole numbers, or for an input number

Tags: python

I got this Python skill assessment for my QA automation job interview and was not able to solve it. Can someone help? Thank you

I've tried to create a function

```
def odd_and_enven_numbers(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number / 2
    else: 
       return number * 3 + 1
```

Hailstone sequence

If the number is even, divide it by 2

If the number is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1

The sequence continues until it is equal to 1, then stops

e.g.
Sequence for `3 = 3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1`

Sequence for `5 = 5,16,8,4,2,1`

Sequence for `7 = 7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1`

Comment: And? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, you only apply your function to `number` once. This can easily be fixed using recursion. We will keep applying the function to the given number until it reaches one. Every time we run the function we append the current value fo `number` to a list called `seq`. Once `number` reaches 1 we can return our sequence.

```
seq = []
def odd_even(number):
    seq.append(number)
    #if you remove this if, we will get a RecursionError.
    #basically you are calling the function for ever and it will never stop
    if number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return odd_even(number / 2)
        else: 
            return odd_even(number * 3 + 1)
    return seq
print(odd_even(3))
```

output

```
[3, 10, 5.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done without recursion like this:

```
def hailstone(x):
  s = []
  while x != 1:
    s.append(x)
    if x % 2 == 0:
      x = x//2
    else:
      x = 3*x+1
  s.append(x)  
  return s
```

And it works like this:

```
hailstone(3)
[3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: @vladimir consider upvoting answers you like, both mine and the one above.